# Driver sky2 in Ubuntu Hardy

Tags: networking, ubuntu

I have a network card:

02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88E8050 PCI-E ASF Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 18)

And it seems the card resets randomly. Here is a dmesg:

```
  
[751806.503694] sky2 eth1: hung mac 124:54 fifo 195 (128:123)
[751806.503702] sky2 eth1: receiver hang detected
[751806.504154] sky2 eth1: disabling interface
[751806.504440] sky2 eth1: enabling interface
[751809.712495] sky2 eth1: Link is up at 1000 Mbps, full duplex, flow control rx
[970196.706605] sky2 eth1: hung mac 0:2 fifo 195 (194:189)
[970196.706611] sky2 eth1: receiver hang detected
[970196.706913] sky2 eth1: disabling interface
[970196.707227] sky2 eth1: enabling interface
[970199.917018] sky2 eth1: Link is up at 1000 Mbps, full duplex, flow control rx
```

It seems there is a problem with the network driver, sky2; but I haven't yet found any answer in other forums. Do you have any suggestions? Can I use another driver for the card? Is it a known bug?

Thanks!

Comment: Does anybody know if this problem is still present in ubuntu 8.10 and/or 9.04??? I mean, migration to a newer version would correct the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The `sky2` driver was unusably bad for many years.

I do believe it's mostly fine these days, the 9.10 version should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround that works reliably for me on approx 10 boxes that have sky2 driver. All my boxes are Centos5 based with kernel 2.6.18 (yes ancient for 2017).
I found that after these log messages ...

```
sky2 eth1: receiver hang detected
sky2 eth1: disabling interface
sky2 eth1: enabling interface
```

... the driver seems to break checksum offloading to hardware. In some experiments I was able to cause it to partially fail just by `ifdown; ifup` sequence which seemed to cause checksum offload to break only for some UDP traffic.

So I just disable the checksum offloading to hardware:

```
ethtool --offload eth1 tx off
```

**WARNING**: for me `ethtool --show-offload eth1` lies and always claims it is off. I can see that setting this to `on` or `off` clearly changes behavior, but querying its state lies and always show as `off`.

Now just to make that apply automatically I put this in `/sbin/ifup-local`:

```
#!/bin/bash
DEVICE=$1
if [[ "$DEVICE" == "eth0" || "$DEVICE" == "eth1" ]] ; then
 ethtool --offload "$DEVICE" tx off
fi
```

but something similar can probably be put that in other places too, e.g. in something like `/etc/network/if-up.d/eth` on debian.